# How can I skip plays using user's prompts?

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook with several plays, to install different apps in a single remote server.

I would need to add interactive prompts, to ask the user if he wants to install a specific app or skip it instead.

This is what I managed to build so far:

Play

```yaml
- name: Telegraf setup
  hosts: new_hcloud
  vars_prompt:
    name: "confirmation"
    prompt: "Do you want to install Telegraf? Answer with 'yes', otherwise press Enter to abort"
    default: "no"
    private: no
  gather_facts: false
  remote_user: root
  become: true
  roles:
  - telegraf
  ignore_errors: true
```

Task

```yaml
- name: Check Confirmation
  fail: msg="Telegraf installation aborted!"
  when: confirmation != "yes"

- name: Install the libselinux-python package for ubuntu
  apt:
    name: python3-selinux
    state: present

- name: Download the package for ubuntu
  get_url:
    url: https://dl.influxdata.com/telegraf/releases/telegraf_{{ telegraf_version }}_amd64.deb
    dest: /tmp/telegraf_{{ telegraf_version }}_amd64.deb
    validate_certs: False
```

Using the `fail` module in my task, completely aborts the specific play, but stops the whole playbook, that's why I added the `ignore_errors: true` directive.

The problem is that the play is not really aborted, and the tasks are played anyway...

How can I modify my code, so to be able to completely skip a whole play, but at the same time, allowing the user to go ahead with remaining plays?

Answer (score 0):

Q: *"**How can I skip a whole play, but at the same time, allow the user to go ahead with the remaining plays?**"*

A: Conditionally *import_role*, e.g. given the roles

```yaml
shell> cat roles/telegraf/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Install Telegraph

shell> cat roles/phone/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: Install Phone
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- name: Telegraf setup
  hosts: new_hcloud
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    name: confirmation
    prompt: |
      Do you want to install Telegraf?
      Answer with 'yes', otherwise, press Enter to abort
    default: "no"
    private: no
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: telegraf
      when: confirmation == "yes"

- name: Phone setup
  hosts: new_hcloud
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    name: confirmation
    prompt: |
      Do you want to install Phone?
      Answer with 'yes', otherwise, press Enter to abort
    default: "no"
    private: no
  tasks:
    - import_role:
        name: phone
      when: confirmation == "yes"
```

give

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml
Do you want to install Telegraf?
Answer with 'yes', otherwise, press Enter to abort
 [no]: no

PLAY [Telegraf setup] ***********************************************************

TASK [telegraf : debug] *********************************************************
skipping: [new_hcloud]
Do you want to install Phone?
Answer with 'yes', otherwise, press Enter to abort
 [no]: yes

PLAY [Phone setup] **************************************************************

TASK [phone : debug] ************************************************************
ok: [new_hcloud] => 
  msg: Install Phone

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************
new_hcloud: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=1 rescued=0 ignored=0
```

---

**Debug**

Q: ***"The output is always skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"***

A: Minimize the code and try to isolate the problem, e.g.

```yaml
shell> ansible --version
ansible [core 2.12.1]
  ...
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) [GCC 9.3.0]
  jinja version = 3.0.1
  libyaml = True
```

```yaml
  vars_prompt:
    name: confirmation
    prompt: |
      Do you want to install Telegraf?
      Answer with 'yes', otherwise, press Enter to abort
    default: "no"
    private: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: confirmation
    - debug:
        var: confirmation|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: confirmation == "yes"
```

gives (for 'yes')

```yaml
Do you want to install Telegraf?
Answer with 'yes', otherwise, press Enter to abort
 [no]: yes

PLAY [Telegraf setup] ******************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************
ok: [new_hcloud] => 
  confirmation: 'yes'

TASK [debug] ***************************************************
ok: [new_hcloud] => 
  confirmation|type_debug: str

TASK [debug] ***************************************************
ok: [new_hcloud] => 
  confirmation == "yes": true
```

or (for 'no')

```yaml
Do you want to install Telegraf?
Answer with 'yes', otherwise, press Enter to abort
 [no]: no

PLAY [Telegraf setup] **********************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************
ok: [new_hcloud] => 
  confirmation: 'no'

TASK [debug] ***************************************************
ok: [new_hcloud] => 
  confirmation|type_debug: str

TASK [debug] ***************************************************
ok: [new_hcloud] => 
  confirmation == "yes": false
```

---

Q: ***The only way I found to make it work is using different names for variable confirmation for each role! (conftelegraf, confphone, and so on....)***

A: Make sure the variable *confirmation* is not defined in the consecutive play(s).

Quoting from the Note in the section [Interactive input: prompts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html#interactive-input-prompts):

> Prompts for individual *vars_prompt* variables will be skipped for any variable that is already defined through the command line *--extra-vars* option, or when running from a non-interactive session (such as cron or Ansible AWX). See [Defining variables at runtime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-at-runtime).

For example

```yaml
- name: Telegraf setup
  hosts: new_hcloud
  gather_facts: no
  vars_prompt:
    name: confirmation
    prompt: |
      Do you want to install Telegraf?
      Answer with 'yes', otherwise, press Enter to abort
    default: "no"
    private: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: confirmation

- name: Test the variable confirmation is defined or not
  hosts: new_hcloud
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: confirmation
```

gives

```yaml
Do you want to install Telegraf?
Answer with 'yes', otherwise, press Enter to abort
 [no]: no

PLAY [Telegraf setup] **********************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [new_hcloud] => 
  confirmation: 'no'

PLAY [Test the variable confirmation is defined or not] ************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************
ok: [new_hcloud] => 
  confirmation: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
```

Comment: I added your code to my playbook, but when running it, all tasks are skipped, even if I type 'yes'...
I added a `debug: var: confirmation` just after `- import_role:` and the output is always `skip_reason": "Conditional result was False`...
Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: I have no idea. I added the debug section.

Comment: The only way I found to make it work is using different names for variable `confirmation` for each role! (`conftelegraf`, `confphone`, and so on....)

Comment: The variable *confirmation* shouldn't be defined in the consecutive play. Minimize the code, see the added section.